# Property 'updateEnabledSubmitSignup' does not exist on type 'typeof SvelteComponentDev' when trying to use an exported Svelte component function

Tags: jestjs, svelte, sveltekit

I want to export a function from a Svelte component and import it into a Jest test file for testing.

My expected result based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287729/how-can-i-export-a-function-from-a-svelte-component-that-changes-a-value-in-the) is that I can do:

```
// index.svelte
<script>
  export function updateEnabledSubmitSignup(email, username, password, confirmedPassword) {
      // ...
  }
</script>
```

and then in my test file:

```
import Signup from "../src/routes/signup/index.svelte"

describe("signup page logic", () => {
  test("ensure that the signup form button enablement conditions work properly", () => {
    console.log(Signup, "5rm")
    const failureOne = Signup.updateEnabledSubmitSignup()
    expect(failureOne).toBe(false)
  })
})
```

But running this code gives

```
tests/signup.test.ts:6:31 - error TS2339: Property 'updateEnabledSubmitSignup' does not exist on type 'typeof SvelteComponentDev'.

    6     const failureOne = Signup.updateEnabledSubmitSignup()
```

It fails also if I do `<script context="module">` with `Property 'updateEnabledSubmitSignup' does not exist on type 'typeof SvelteComponentDev'.`

If I try a named import like

`import { updateEnabledSubmitSignup } from "../src/routes/signup/index.svelte"`

then running the test gives `error TS2614: Module '"*.svelte"' has no exported member 'updateEnabledSubmitSignup'. Did you mean to use 'import updateEnabledSubmitSignup from "*.svelte"' instead?`

Anyone know how to do this please? [This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/sgrf4e/how_do_you_import_a_function_from_a_component/) claims "You can use the  tag at the top of your component to export a function." But even though I do that, the import fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions exported from the regular script are on the instance, e.g.

```js
let signup;
onMount(() => signup.updateEnabledSubmitSignup());
```

```html
<Signup bind:this={signup} />
```

Functions exported from the `context=module` script are named exports of the file.

If you get a type error from that, it is because your tooling did not determine the types correctly (it generically says `*.svelte` instead of the concrete type of this specific component). Question being, why your tests are doing type checking in the first place.

Comment: I use a `.ts` jest test file! hence why tests are doing type checking. I'll try with `.js`

Comment: The build tool plugins for Svelte should be able to generate correct types for each component; you could look into how to write those to `d.ts` files for the tests or maybe this can be integrated another way if you want to stick with TS.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because I was able to write a successful unit test using your advice. One step was to convert my ts test file into a js test file. The other was to use `context="module"`